# How can I make Drupal server small bits of content via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

If you want to make Drupal server (themed) pages, it is pretty straight forward, but what if you want it to serve small chunks of data (e.g. as JSON).

I'd like to have parts of my page load asynchronously, e.g. a block that refreshes every 10' with the active users.

What is the proper way to go about it in Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh

Comment: Awesome module Antonio! I didn't know something like that existed. 
Having said that, I'm actually looking for some sort of howto in order to build my own modules that use Drupal+AJAX and understand how something like that actually works. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: well, you'd have to write a module that declares a path, then write some code that returns drupal_json() or something related. Then with a little bit of javascript, doing setInterval(), you can request that page and plug the json bits into your block.